# How to remove slightly modified duplicate images?

Tags: bash, imagemagick

I have thousands of images that I have made in my phone and DSLR over last couple of years and never given a thought about photo management until recently and it is a mess now. I used

```
fdupes -r . > picLog &
```

to retrieve information about duplicate images and then used `fdupes` again to delete them.

However, there are still several hundreds (if not thousands) of images left that are duplicate. Hence, I used `identify -verbose image.jpg` of to compare some images that `fdupes` and `fslint-gui` both fail to differentiate. Is there any way I can compare those and delete the duplicates?

```
identify -verbose 8.jpg > log1
identify -verbose 35.jpg > log2
diff log1 log2
```

[image: Here is the output of diff]

Comment: Welcome, you say *"It looks like those have slightly modified time"*, can you clarify this statement?

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity: I may have understood it wrong. I deleted that line and added the output of `diff file1 file2`

Comment: Are they the exact same images, meaning identical?

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity: yes, they are. In fact, I downloaded both of them from google photos. Once with `rclone`. Then with Google Takeout to make sure I do not lose any of the pictures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Compute the hash of each image without the metadata**

If you are looking to identify images where the image data is identical but the metadata differs (rotation is usually noted just in the metadata), here is a script I have used in the past:

```
find -type f -a '(' \
        -iname '*.jpg' -o \
        -iname '*.jpeg' -o \
        -iname '*.mov' -o \
        -iname '*.mpg' -o \
        -iname '*.mpeg' -o \
        -iname '*.avi' \
    ')' -print0 |perl -n0e '
    my $f = $_;
    chomp($f);
    (my $fe = $f) =~ s|\x27|\x27\\\x27\x27|g;
    my $md5;
    if($f =~ m|\.[aA][vV][iI]$| or $f =~ m|\.[mM][pP][gG]$|) {
      $md5 = `cat \x27$fe\x27 |md5sum`;
    } else {
      $md5 = `exiftool \x27$fe\x27 -all= -o - |md5sum`;
    }
    chomp($md5); $md5 =~ s| +-\n||;
    print("$md5 $f\n");
' |tee photo-signatures.txt
```

The above computes the **MD5 hash of the image data** of all photos and videos in the current directory and subdirectories.  To see duplicates, run:

```
cat photo-signatures.txt |sort |uniq --check-chars=32 --all-repeated
```

To see what duplicate photos **will get deleted** duplicates, run:

```
cat photo-signatures.txt |sort |uniq --check-chars=32 --all-repeated=prepend |sed -e '/^$/,+1d' |grep -Po '^.{33}\K.*'
```

Finally, to **actually delete** the photos listed by the above command, run it again with  `|xargs -d '\n' rm` at the end.

**Explanations of what the above commands do**

- the `-print0` of `find` and `-0` of `perl` use `\x00` rather than `\n` to split records
- `find ... -print0`: find all files with *any* of the given extensions, case insensitive
- `perl -n0e ...`: Perl script, process one file at a time

  - `(my $fe = $f) =~ s|\x27|\x27\\\x27\x27|g;`: single quotes become `'\''` (Bash escape)
  - `` $md5 = `cat \x27$fe\x27 |md5sum`; ``: for *video* files (no metadata support in `exiftool`), compute MD5 hash of entire file
  - `` $md5 = `exiftool \x27$fe\x27 -all= -o - |md5sum`; ``: call `exiftool` to strip all photo metadata and output to stdout; compute MD5 hash
  - `chomp($md5); $md5 =~ s| +-\n||;`: remove the   `-` that `md5sum` puts at the end of each line when it's input is stdin
  - `print("$md5 $f\n");`: output the MD5 hash and filename
- `|tee photo-signatures.txt`: save the results to a file and also display them
- `cat photo-signatures.txt |sort |uniq --check-chars=32 --all-repeated`: output lines of which there is more than one (`--all-repeated`), but only comparing the MD5 hash part of each line (`--check-chars=32`)
- `cat photo-signatures.txt |sort |uniq --check-chars=32 --all-repeated=prepend |sed -e '/^$/,+1d' |grep -Po '^.{33}\K.*'`: same as above but add a blank line before each group of identical MD5 hashes (`--all-repeated=prepend`), then use `sed` to delete these blank lines and the first line after it (i.e. the file we're keeping), and finally `grep` to keep only the filename portion of each line
- `|xargs -d '\n' rm`: remove each file read from stdin

Comment: Perfect. Thank you, @bitinerant

Comment: Would you mind giving short explanation what each of lines do?

Comment: @Pladin - you're welcome. I have added some descriptions to my answer.

Comment: It helps tremendously. Thanks, again. I do not have reputation "ENOUGH" to upvote your answer :(

Answer (score 2):

Some time ago when I was using Ubuntu 10.04, I used [dupeGuru](https://dupeguru.voltaicideas.net/) to identify duplicate photos. It did a pretty good job. Haven't used it for long time, so I don't know how the current version performs, but you may give it a try.

Comment: Thanks, @raj. I will definitely give it a try